# How to create a countdown timer for each item in an array?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, redux

In my React app, I have a list of orders which are supposed to be shown to the user for only 30 seconds so each order has a value of 30 seconds for its duration propery:

```
[
  {
    ...,
    ...,
    duration: 30
  },
  {
    ...,
    ...,
    duration: 30
  },
  ...
]
```

I'm using Redux Toolkit to store their data so that I can render the UI of these items in various components. I tried to create an action which gets dispatched every 1 second to decrement the duration by one:

```
decrementCountdown: (state, action) => {
  const order = state.entities[action.payload];
  
  if (order) order.duration -= 1;
}
```

Then, in `App.jsx`, I dispatch the action using `setInterval` inside a loop:

```
useEffect(() => {
  let countdown;

  for (order of orders) {
    // Run until the duration reaches zero
    if (order.duration > 1) {
      countdown = setInterval(() => dispatch(decrementCountdown(order?.id)), 1000);
    }
  }

return () => clearInterval(countdown);
}, [orders])
```

The challenging part is that the timers have to be synched so that everywhere that the items are shown, the same remaining time is shown and decremented.

The method I have used didn't help me much. Especially when more that one order was present. In that case, the new order's duration wouldn't decrement and it caused an infinite loop inside the `useEffect`.

Is there any way I can create a countdown for each one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Alexey's response and comment I figured that I needed to create a separate Redux Slice dedicated to each order's duration. I was already using the `Entity Adapter` of Redux Toolkit so the order and duration slices looked like this:

**`orderSlice.js`**:

```
order: {
  ids: [
    0: 500,
    1: 600
  ],
  entities: {
    500: {
      id: 500,
      ...
    },
    600: {
      id: 600,
      ...
    },
  }
}
```

**`orderDurationSlice.js`**:

```
orderDurtaion: {
  ids: [
    0: 500,
    1: 600
  ],
  entities: {
    500: {
      id: 500,
      duration: 30
    },
    600: {
      id: 600,
      duration: 30
    },
  }
}
```

After each order arrives via a `Socket` connection, it gets added into both of the slices (Only the order `id` gets added to the `orderDuration` slice in order to correspond to the complete order object inside the `order` slice).

The challenging part was to start the countdown timer for each one of the orders as soon as they arrive and also have it as a top-level service running independently of the component lifecycle so that each component that requires it could access it.

I was already using Redux Toolkit's `Listener Middleware` to handle the `Socket` connection and after someone on Reddit recommended the use of Redux's `middleware` to handle this, I realized that I just had to create another `listener` as a kind of countdown service.

This listener would only run if the `orderDuration` slice is filled and the instance of `setInterval` is `undefined`.

**`socketListenerMiddleware.js`**:

```
// Order countdown interval instance
let countdown;

// Create the middleware instance and methods
const socketListenerMiddleware = createListenerMiddleware();

// Handle each order's duration countdown after a new order arrives
socketListenerMiddleware.startListening({
  predicate: (action, currentState, previousState) => {
    // Check if the interval instance is undefined and the order duration slice is full
    return !countdown && currentState.orderDuration?.ids.length;
  },
  effect: (action, listenerApi) => {
    // Cancel any in-progress instances of this listener
    listenerApi.cancelActiveListeners();

    // Handle the countdown
    countdown = setInterval(() => {
      // Select all of the order durations
      // These are being selected inside of the interval to always get the most-updated array
      const orderDurations = orderDurationSelectors.selectAll(
        listenerApi.getState(),
      );

      // Loop through each order duration to get each item
      for (const order of orderDurations) {
        // Start the countdown
        listenerApi.dispatch(decrementDuration(order?.id));

        // If the order duration state is less than or equal to zero, remove the order and its corresponding duration
        if (order?.duration <= 0) {
          listenerApi.dispatch(removeOrder(order?.id));
          listenerApi.dispatch(removeDuration(order?.id));
        }
      }

      // If the order duration slice gets empty, clear the interval and reset its instance
      if (!orderDurations.length) {
        clearInterval(countdown);
        countdown = undefined;
      }
    }, 1000);
  },
});
```

**The main part which handles the countdown is here**:

Here, only one instance of `setInterval` is created which loops over the `orderDuration` array to get each one of the items and dispatches an action which decrements each order's duration by 1.

If the order's duration gets to zero, two dispatched actions remove the order (in `order` slice) and its corresponding duration (in `orderDuration` slice).

Finally, outside of the loop an `if` condition checks if the `orderDuration` slice gets empty and if so, it clears the `interval` and resets its instance.

```
// Handle the countdown
    countdown = setInterval(() => {
      // Select all of the order durations
      // These are being selected inside of the interval to always get the most-updated array
      const orderDurations = orderDurationSelectors.selectAll(
        listenerApi.getState(),
      );

      // Loop through each order duration to get each item
      for (const order of orderDurations) {
        // Start the countdown
        listenerApi.dispatch(decrementDuration(order?.id));

        // If the order duration state is less than or equal to zero, remove the order and its corresponding duration
        if (order?.duration <= 0) {
          listenerApi.dispatch(removeOrder(order?.id));
          listenerApi.dispatch(removeDuration(order?.id));
        }
      }

      // If the order duration slice gets empty, clear the interval and reset its instance
      if (!orderDurations.length) {
        clearInterval(countdown);
        countdown = undefined;
      }
    }, 1000);
```

I then access each order's duration via selector's inside components.

Hope this solution helps anyone dealing with this kind of question.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to keep countdown in store? It is very bad idea, because every second u will trigger rerenders of components that using this data.

Maybe u can create an CountDown component?

```
function CountDown(props) {
   const [counter, setCounter] = useState(+props.duration);
   useEffect(() => {
       const interval = setInterval(() => {
           setCounter(counter - 1);
           if (counter <= 0) {
              clearInterval(interval);
              props.onEnd?.(); // here u can pass any actions after countDown is ended
           }
       }), 1000);

       return () => clearInterval(interval);
   }, []);
   return <div>{props.counter}</div>
}
```

But if u need to keep countdowns in redux i recommend you to move it from orders objects and place it to array for example. In this array u will be able to keep counters and intervals for every order.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I'll try it out and tell you how it goes. I do agree that putting them in Redux is gonna cause many performance issues, but the problem is that these orders need to start their timer as soon as they arrive from the `Socket` connection, so that when the user navigates to the component which is showing them, their duration has already been decremented since the time they arrived first.

Comment: If you whant to have independend countdowns from render, then just create array of countdowns, or object orderId => timer. And you will need one interval which will iterate through all elements in that array and decrease timer, and if timer ended you can perform any actions